Why do only 2 USB cameras work while 4 USB cameras cannot stream at once?
I have 4 480p USB 2.0 cameras.  Any idea why I can't stream 4 feeds at once?
I am using a VL817 USB hub for all the cameras.  It seems not the problem of bandwidth as the average frame size for one camera is 600kb 30fps.
Any idea why it is limited to 2 cameras?



Please edit your question to include the makes and models of the cameras. What video bitrates and codecs do the cameras support? How do you have them configured w.r.t. video codecs and bitrates? Pulling a still from a camera and checking its size is not a reliable way to know the video frame size, as a still might get compressed with a still image codec that's not the same as the video codec in use.

Uncompressed full-color (24 bits per pixel / 8 bits per color, no chroma subsampling) 480p30 SD video is 221Mbps, which is more than half of USB 2.0's 480Mbps signaling rate (and USB is infamous for its inefficiency, so you never get close to 480Mbps).

Does the USB hub have an external power supply, or is it relying solely on bus power?

@sawdust yes the USB hub has an external power supply

@Spiff I don't have info on who makes the camera, the camera is using YUY2, i'm using AMCAP to obtain these information including the video frame size

You need to add captions to your photos. A Google search indicates that a SN3762L is a USB-to-camera adapter chip, and nothing else. No datasheet is available. I can't see any image sensor in your photo. There's a lot of cable visible in your photo. Exactly what are the USB cable lengths involved with each camera?

"I am using a VL817 USB hub for all the cameras" - Why? Your PC has two USB host controllers. Try to distribute the throughput load of the four cameras among both  USB host controllers.

If you unplug one of the working cameras, does a different one start working?

Just for reference, higher-quality cameras typically use much better compression methods like MJPEG or H.264 to achieve higher resolutions and framerates. Depending on your use case you may have some luck if you can find a MJPEG-capable webcam, and then running it at a lower resolution if you need multiple on one host controller.

@Bob manufacturers have got lazy.  Over 20 years ago there were VGA-resolution USB1 webcams using MJPEG.  Some of them used rather nice CCD sensors (which at the time were much better than CMOS)

@Spiff OTOH the streaming software could be pulling a series of stills rather than an actual stream even when displaying video.  Which makes your point about being sure you're measuring the right thing just as important

If it's a desktop, you can add one or more USB cards.  Many years ago I used one that had multiple host controllers on it

It looks like you have two root hubs... is the other one accessible?  Usually there's at least a single port on the system for one, with all the others hubbed off the other.  If you can split your cameras so that they're using both root hubs, you should have enough bandwidth.

You probably a device to merge the 4 usb cameras into 1 virtual camera feed, and plug that in 1 usb port ? Look in https://www.google.com/search?q=video+multiplexer++multiple+usb+cameras+merge , but beware some may just "switch" between multiple feed: you need one that merges together the 4 simultaneous feeds. I believe https://www.arducam.com/multi-camera-adapter-module-raspberry-pi/ is one (?)

I believe from the information you've given, that you are exceeding the bandwidth of a single USB 2.0 bus when you try to use a third camera of this type. Here's the calculation:
480p implies 640 * 480 = 307,200 pixels per frame.
At 8 bits per color channel that would normally be 24 bits per pixel, so 307,200 * 24 = 7,372,800 bits per frame.
But you said in the comments that your cameras are doing YUY2 a.k.a. YUV2, which means they are using 4:2:2 chroma subsampling to reduce bandwidth by throwing away some color data. Explaining chroma subsampling is beyond the scope of this Answer, but my calculations say the 4:2:2 subsampling mode reduces the bits per pixel by one-third, so each frame would be about 4,915,200 bits.
There are 8,192 bits per kilobyte (or, more precisely, per KibiByte), so 4,915,200 / 8,192 = 600 KiB. I think this checks out with your observation that each frame was "600kb"; I think wherever you got that 600 number for the frame size, it was reporting in KibiBytes, not kilobits.
So all of this so far indicates to me that your cameras are sending an uncompressed 480p30, 4:2:2 (YUY2/YUV2) video stream.
So each frame is 4,915,200 bits, * 30 fps = 147,456,000 bits per second. ~147 Mbps fits within USB 2.0's 480 Mbps raw signaling rate before overhead.
A second camera would double the total bandwidth usage on the USB bus, to 294,912,000 bits per second. That seems like it should still fit within USB 2.0's bus speed.
A third camera would bring the total bus bandwidth usage to 442,368,000 bits per second, which seems too close to 480,000,000 to fit, given USB's reputation for having a lot of overhead. If USB's overhead hits 8% or more, that third camera's stream won't fit.
As fellow SuperUser regular @sawdust noted in the comments, your USB device tree screenshot shows that your PC has two USB host controllers (two separate USB buses), so you might well be able to work around this problem by figuring out which USB ports are connected to which host controller, and connect two cameras to each controller, instead of trying to put all four cameras on a single USB 2.0 bus.

Seeing as xHCI (the PC part) is USB 3.0 and a VL817 hub is USB 3.1 Gen1, do the USB 2.0 limitations still apply? Or does attaching USB 2.0 devices slow down all the USB 3+ interfaces?

@AndrewMorton All usb 2 limitations still apply. For practical purposes,  USB 3 is actually three separate interdependent busse: USB 2, Superspeed, and the control channel. The high bandwidth comes from the superspeed link. But only USB 3 native devices can use that. For USB 2 devices, all the USB 3 functionality and transfers are invisible.

I would expect that plugging in a third camera would cause all three to stop working, or at least degrade, as all three fight over available bandwidth.  Does the new camera (or the computer) have some way to know that it wouldn't have enough bandwidth and just not even try?

@Bobson USB 2.0 is a polling based protocol, the computer keeps asking things like "hey keyboard, what are the pressed keys". Windows allocated USB2.0 bandwidth in a first come, first serve order, earlier registered drivers are given priority

I didn't know that any contemporary device sends uncompressed video, even if it's only 480p. Yikes.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Pretty much all USB Cameras can send uncompressed video, just maybe not by default. It is a sensible fall-back in case the host cannot decode any of the compressed formats or compression artifacts would be a problem for the actual application.

Your VL817 USB hub uses a USB 2.0 USB multi-tt hub. I cite from the last link:

About USB 2.0 Hubports, ... the upstream link on any of our USB 2.0 Hubports is 480 Mbps. The aggregate bandwidth of all ports on the hub cannot exceed 480 Mbps at any given instant.

Given the calculations others have provided, your USB Hub can support the bandwidth of maximum 2 of your cameras, before those 480 Mbps are saturated.
See also this other SuperUser answer, which basically says that you'll encounter the same issue on any USB hub. The USB 2.0 is a separate protocol from the USB 3.0 / 3.1 protocol (and is separate from the USB 4.0 protocol). This means that the USB controller of your PC establishes a USB 2.0 connection to any USB hub which is separate from the USB 3.0 connection. So, for any hub the total of any USB 2.0 connections cannot exceed 480 Mbps.
To resolve this bottleneck, you'll need to hook up two of your cameras to a different hub, or connect them directly to your PC, taking care that there are no more than 2 cameras per USB Root hub: according to USB tree view you provide, your PC has two USB root hubs. You might try-and-test to which ports you'll need to connect the webcams.

The key problem is that a normal USB 3 hub* is actually two hubs in one box. The hub for high/full/low speed peripherals is entirely separate from the hub for superspeed peripherals.
So if all your perhiperals are USB 2, then a USB 3 hub doesn't help you get any more bandwidth. To get more bandwidth you generaly need to get the devices onto seperate USB host controllers.
Sometimes you can achieve that by rearranging ports. Your USB viewer shows two "controllers" but it may be that only one is exposed externally, or it may be that one "controller" is for full/low/high speed (aka USB 2) devices only and the other is for superspeed devices only.
If you have a desktop, then a way to be sure a device is on a different controller is to use a PCI or PCIe card for some of the cameras, if you are on an older laptop then expresscard can fill a similar role. On a newer laptop thunderbolt may be an option.

They probably don't need to add hardware. Their screenshot shows two USB host controllers. They just need to work out which of their PC's external USB ports connect to which host controller (by plugging things into different ports and refreshing the USB device tree display), and then plug two cameras into the bus created by the second host controller. If they discover none of the external ports are on the second controller, THEN they would need to add a PCIe card.

The screenshot does show two controllers, but I've often seen systems where the full/low/high speed stuff shows up as a seperate controller from the superspeed stuff.

Microsoft calls those companion controllers.

to further @user20574 's point, "full" and "low" speeds actually refer to USB 1 signaling rates (12Mbit/sec and 1.5Mbit/sec, respectively)
